# Unable to load Action error while deploying struts2 war file on weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: struts2, weblog

Unable to load configuration. - action -

zip:C:/Oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/se1/q9j1fw/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/stru
ts.xml:10:76
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:509)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:73)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:61)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager$FilterInitAction.run(FilterManager.java:343)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: Unable to load configuration. - action - zip:C:/Oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/se1/q9j1fw/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_ge
n.jar!/struts.xml:10:76
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:957)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:463)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:496)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:73)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: Error building results for action hello in namespace /hello - action - zip:C:/Oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/se1/q9j
1fw/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/struts.xml:10:76
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:467)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:572)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:326)
        at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:105)

This is my struts.xml

?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

```
<package name="hello" extends="struts-default" namespace="/hello">

    <action name="hello" class="com.struts2Ex1.Struts2Ex1" method="sayHello">
        <result type="input">/sample.jsp</result>
        <result type="success">/success.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

I created Struts2Ex1.java action under com.struts2Ex1 package.

Please help on this I am unable to run application from 1 week.

What weblogic does during WAR deployment(obviously it internally explodes) it puts all the files reside in web-inf/classes folder into jar called _wl_cls_gen.jar file and copies into web-inf/lib directory under domain stage folder. This is where the problem during deployment as my java class was unable to read the xml.

Weblogic throwing following exception at the time of deploying war file

```
ERROR Dispatcher Dispatcher initialization failed
```

Unable to load configuration. - action - zip:C:/Oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/XXXXX/XXXXX/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.ja
r!/struts.xml:7:44
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:957)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:463)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:496)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:73)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:61)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager$FilterInitAction.run(FilterManager.java:343)

Comment: So... `Error building results for action hello in namespace /hello ` indicates there's something wrong with your `struts.xml`, which you don't include, so there's zero way anybody can help.

Comment: What weblogic does during WAR deployment(obviously it internally explodes) it puts all the files reside in web-inf/classes folder into jar called _wl_cls_gen.jar file and copies into web-inf/lib directory under domain stage folder. This is where the problem during deployment as my java class was unable to read the xml.