# Unable to load Action class while deploying struts2.5 war file on weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: java, struts2, weblogic, war, weblogic-10.x

[Unable to load Action error while deploying struts2 war file on weblogic 10.3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812659/unable-to-load-action-error-while-deploying-struts2-war-file-on-weblogic-10-3-6)

The above question is very similar to the issue I'm facing but there is no solution provided.
I have an application in struts2.5 which I have exported to a *.war file and trying to deploy it to weblogic 10.3.6(running on java7).
During deployment I get an error that the Action class is not found (when I can see it present in the war file's WEB-INF/classes).

As mentioned by user3898783 in above link- "What weblogic does during
WAR deployment(obviously it internally explodes) it puts all the files reside in web-inf/classes folder into jar called _wl_cls_gen.jar file and copies into web-inf/lib directory under domain stage folder." - similar is my problem.
I am currently using the wls:prefer-web-inf-classes"true" /wls:prefer-web-inf-classes configuration in my weblogic.xml file which hasn't really solved my problem.

Weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
     <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
     </wls:container-descriptor>
     
        
    <wls:session-descriptor> 
        <wls:cookies-enabled>true</wls:cookies-enabled>
     </wls:session-descriptor>
     
</wls:weblogic-web-app>

<May 23, 2019 1:00:02 AM CDT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101165> <Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.
Unable to load configuration. - action - zip:/apps/bea/wls103/user_projects/domains/mydomain/servers/mymanagedserver/tmp/_WL_user/myapp/4bdx7o/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/struts.xml:16:97
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:509)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:73)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:61)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager$FilterInitAction.run(FilterManager.java:343)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: Unable to load configuration. - action - zip:/apps/bea/wls103/user_projects/domains/mydomain/servers/mymanagedserver/tmp/_WL_user/myapp/4bdx7o/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/struts.xml:16:97
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:957)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:463)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:496)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:73)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: Action class [com.myapp.struts.actions.LoginAction] not found - action - zip:/apps/bea/wls103/user_projects/domains/mydomain/servers/mymanagedserver/tmp/_WL_user/myapp/4bdx7o/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/struts.xml:16:97
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:508)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:457)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:572)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:326)
        at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:108)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

I checked my `struts.xml(struts.xml:16:97)` - and it is pointing to the LoginAction action class mapping, which obviously its not able to find under the weblogic `"../domains/../mymanagedserver/tmp/_WL_user/myapp/4bdx7o/war/WEB-INF/classes"`

Thanking you in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to figure this out. The culprit has been the compiler compliance level in my eclipse project.  Although I was using jdk1.7 in my project buildpath, I should have also checked for the projects compiler compliance version in Eclipse which was 1.8 (proj right click> JavaCompiler> I set it to 1.7). 
Also, I was using javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar - I switched to servlet2.5 as I read somewhere that weblogic10.3.x is only compliant upto servlet2.5.

I hope this helps someone looking for a solution to similar problem.